# inject the Authenticated User in HTTP header from WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

How I can inject the Authenticated User in HTTP header from WSO2 ESB Webservices. I want to inject auth user as a http header and read from back-end.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-) What have you tried so far?
Please look at [ask]
and [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Before the send : endpoint add following properties.

```
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
 name="Authorization"
 expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('username:password'))"
 scope="transport"/>
```